# External providers is not getting registered in resteasy

Tags: tomcat, resteasy

I was using paramConverter provider in resteasy for handling complex string parameters. I have registered it in web.xml under resteasy.providers context and annotated it with @Provider. It was working fine until i started to use interceptors. After then it started ignoring the providers and now even i hace removed the interceptor class it is not registering providers. Does anyone has any clue??
I am using resteasy-jaxrs-3.0-beta-6 version and my web.xml looks like -

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

```
<display-name>RestEasy Simple Service</display-name>
<description>RestEasy Simple Service</description>


<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap 
     </listener-class>
</listener>  


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.rest.myRESTApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>    

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

 <context-param>
     <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
     <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
 </context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.rest.myProviderXmlJson</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your web.xml?  Also, what version of Resteasy are you using?

Comment: heyy @gwhitake i have provided my web.xml and version that I m using.

Comment: When you look in the logs on the console can you see myProviderXmlJson being scanned?

Comment: yeah..it is compiling and being also stored under classes of war built.Moreover if i use MessageBodyWriter also and put it in resteasy.providers,writer is being called and working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to clear the root directory of webapp under tomcat server. If its not clear then sometime it gives some random errors.